# Why does an IE window pops up when closing a form on WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted handler

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a form that has a WebBrowser control. Onload, it navigates to some URL.
On DocumentCompleted event handler, after getting the needed data the form is closed. This works most of the time, but sometime it pops up an IE window w/ the same URL after the form has already closed.

I noticed that in DebugView, it logs `m_useSurfacePresenter 1`. When this gets logged before the Close() is called, there is no popup. But when this gets logged after the Close() is called, then the popup appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the JavaScript .onunload event in that document, if it is set to open a new window (browser) when that page is unloading, then it will be triggered when you close your winform which is hosting the webbrowser control, and in turn, the page.

So, when you close the winform, the page's onUnload event in the webbrowser control will also be triggered as a result due to the way the events are chained in a Document/Page --> WB Control --> WinForms Form setup.

You can actually set this to nothing, by running a particular JS command directed to the page in the WB control, you can set the .OnUnload event to "`function () {};`", which will ensure whatever it is set to will be turned into Nothing/Null. Here is a code example:

> window.onunload = function () { };

Let me know how it goes, and I will help you out if that doesn't fix it. Notice the above is JS, and there are ways to execute JS directly from teh WB Control, many examples on the web, there are actually 2 ways, one using .execScript and another one using the newer method, which is .InvokeScript.